# What's the relative speed of floating point add vs. floating point multiply

Tags: floating-point, x86, mips, numerical-computing, flops

A decade or two ago, it was worthwhile to write numerical code to avoid using multiplies and divides and use addition and subtraction instead.  A good example is using [forward differences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ForwardDifference.html) to evaluate a polynomial curve instead of computing the polynomial directly.

Is this still the case, or have modern computer architectures advanced to the point where *,/ are no longer many times slower than +,- ?

To be specific, I'm interested in compiled C/C++ code running on modern typical x86 chips with extensive on-board floating point hardware, not a small micro trying to do FP in software.  I realize pipelining and other architectural enhancements preclude specific cycle counts, but I'd still like to get a useful intuition.

Comment: Related: [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899202) compares things on modern x86 microarchitectures.  TL:DR `divps` can be ok for throughput if you don't do it very often, and always has much worse latency.

Comment: Related: [Why does this code execute more slowly after strength-reducing multiplications to loop-carried additions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72306573) re: forward differences for plotting a quadratic.  Easy to make it slower if you're not careful, since FP addition has essentially the same performance as FP multiplication on modern x86.  (On Intel CPUs from Skylake onward, *exactly* the same performance, until Alder Lake has lower latency `addps`/`pd` by 1 cycle.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It also depends on instruction mix.  Your processor will have several computation units standing by at any time, and you'll get maximum throughput if all of them are filled all the time.  So, executing a loop of mul's is just as fast as executing a loop or adds - but the same doesn't hold if the expression becomes more complex.

For example, take this loop:

```
for(int j=0;j<NUMITER;j++) {
  for(int i=1;i<NUMEL;i++) {
    bla += 2.1 + arr1[i] + arr2[i] + arr3[i] + arr4[i] ;
  }
}
```

for NUMITER=10^7, NUMEL=10^2, both arrays initialized to small positive numbers (NaN is much slower), this takes 6.0 seconds using doubles on a 64-bit proc.  If I replace the loop with

```
bla += 2.1 * arr1[i] + arr2[i] + arr3[i] * arr4[i] ;
```

It only takes 1.7 seconds... so since we "overdid" the additions, the muls were essentially free; and the reduction in additions helped.  It get's more confusing:

```
bla += 2.1 + arr1[i] * arr2[i] + arr3[i] * arr4[i] ;
```

-- same mul/add distribution, but now the constant is added in rather than multiplied in -- takes 3.7 seconds.  Your processor is likely optimized to perform typical numerical computations more efficiently; so dot-product like sums of muls and scaled sums are about as good as it gets; adding constants isn't nearly as common, so that's slower...

```
bla += someval + arr1[i] * arr2[i] + arr3[i] * arr4[i] ; /*someval == 2.1*/
```

again takes 1.7 seconds.

```
bla += someval + arr1[i] + arr2[i] + arr3[i] + arr4[i] ; /*someval == 2.1*/
```

(same as initial loop, but without expensive constant addition: 2.1 seconds)

```
bla += someval * arr1[i] * arr2[i] * arr3[i] * arr4[i] ; /*someval == 2.1*/
```

(mostly muls, but one addition:1.9 seconds)

So, basically; it's hard to say which is faster, but if you wish to avoid bottlenecks, more important is to have a sane mix, avoid NaN or INF, avoid adding constants.  Whatever you do, make sure you test, and test various compiler settings, since often small changes can just make the difference.

Some more cases:

```
bla *= someval; // someval very near 1.0; takes 2.1 seconds
bla *= arr1[i] ;// arr1[i] all very near 1.0; takes 66(!) seconds
bla += someval + arr1[i] * arr2[i] + arr3[i] * arr4[i] ; // 1.6 seconds
bla += someval + arr1[i] * arr2[i] + arr3[i] * arr4[i] ; //32-bit mode, 2.2 seconds
bla += someval + arr1[i] * arr2[i] + arr3[i] * arr4[i] ; //32-bit mode, floats 2.2 seconds
bla += someval * arr1[i]* arr2[i];// 0.9 in x64, 1.6 in x86
bla += someval * arr1[i];// 0.55 in x64, 0.8 in x86
bla += arr1[i] * arr2[i];// 0.8 in x64, 0.8 in x86, 0.95 in CLR+x64, 0.8 in CLR+x86
```

Comment: Instruction mix is a good point, I have people I work with who insist that a 200 Floating Point DSP is going to out perform a 600 fixed point DSP.  They do absolutely no tight loop processing, and spend more time processing I/O than doing calcuations.  A faster fixed point processor would win based on the overall instruction mix, but people just think FP units are magic rather than a HW implementation of a datastructure.

Comment: nice explanation with intuitive examples!

Comment: This is relevant to the topic but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Noob there is no one correct answer, which I try to explain above.  Or to put it another way: the real answer is "it depends", which isn't particularly helpful, especially since the number of things it depends on is huge and growing with each new chip, unusual execution environment, optimizing compiler, combination of SIMD modes used etc.

In general, it's best to regard them as approximately equally expensive - when the difference becomes meaningful you're also at a level of micro-optimization that requires careful case-by-case analysis anyhow.

Answer (score 19):

In theory the information is here:

[Intel®64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual, APPENDIX C INSTRUCTION LATENCY AND THROUGHPUT](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf)

For every processor they list, the latency on FMUL is very close to that of FADD or FDIV.  On some of the older processors, FDIV is 2-3 time slower than that, while on newer processors, it's the same as FMUL.

Caveats:

1. The document I linked actually says you can't rely on these numbers in real life since the processor will do what it wishes to make things faster if it's correct.
2. There's a good chance your compiler will decide to use one of the many newer instruction sets that have a floating-point multiply / divide available.
3. This is a complicated document only meant to be read by compiler writers and I might have gotten it wrong.  Like I'm not clear why the FDIV latency number is completely missing for some of the CPUs.

Comment: Very cool document.  I think one thing that remains consistent (and this document shows it) is that division is still far slower than multiplication, addition, and subtraction.  From the looks of this document, the latency of double-precision division is 10X slower than multiplication. So, for example, I believe calling x = y * 0.5 should be faster than calling x = y / 2.

Comment: @SteveWortham Can you please point to the page where you found the info about fdiv being 10x slower than fmul?

Comment: @user247077 - I don't remember.  This was a couple years ago.  However, there are charts in this document that reference the latency of a lot of different commands.  And FMUL is certainly faster than FDIV in these charts.  Then there's DIV r64 and MUL r64 on page C-33 which have a huge gap between them in latency.  Last year I may have hit these instructions (or an AMD equivalent) when I had created a 64-bit application to benchmark the performance difference between multiplication and division... http://swortham.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-much-faster-is-multiplication-than.html

Comment: The same thing is basically still true on modern x86 with SSE2 FP math.  `addsd` and `mulsd` are very similar, while `divsd` is higher latency and *much* worse throughput.  [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899202).  (Haswell/Broadwell have twice the multiply throughput vs. add, but add latency is at least as good as multiply.  So that's funky until Skylake, when add/mul both run identically on the same FMA execution units, both 4c latency with 2 per clock throughput.  https://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: Also related: [Why does Intel's Haswell chip allow floating point multiplication to be twice as fast as addition?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/452366)

Comment: This doc is relevent for Intel Atom CPU only it seems. I didn't find data for other CPU types in this doc

Answer (score 9):

The best way to answer this question is to actually write a benchmark/profile of the processing you need to do.   Empirical should be used over theoretical when ever possible.  Especially when it easy to attain.

If you already know different implementations of the Math you need to do, you could write a a few different code transfermations of the math and see where your performance peaks.  This will allow the processor/compiler to generate different execution streams to fill the processor pipelines and give you a concrete answer to your answer.

If you are interest in specifically the performance of DIV/MUL/ADD/SUB type instructions you could even toss in some inline assembly to control specifically which variants of these instruction are executed.  However you need to make sure you're keeping multilple execution units busy to get a good idea of the performance the system is capable of.

Also doing something like this would allow you to compare performance on multiple variations of the processor by simply running the same program on them, and could also allow you to factor in the motherboard differences.

Edit:

Basic architecture of a +- is identical.  So they logically take the same time to compute.  * on the other hand, require multiple layers, typically constructed out of "full adders" to complete a single operation.  This garentees that while a * can be issued to the pipeline every cycle it will have a higher latency than an add/subtract circuit.  A fp / operation is typically implemented using an approximation method which iteratively converges towards the correct answer over time.  These types of approximations are typically implemented via multiplication.  So for floating point you can generally assume division will take longer because it's impractical to "unroll" the multiplications (which is already a large circuit in and of it's self) into pipeline of a multitude of multiplier circuits.  Still the performance of a given system is best measured via testing.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find a definitive reference, but extensive experimentation tells me that float multiplication nowadays is just about the same speed as addition and subtraction, while division isn't (but not "many times" slower, either).  You can get the intuition you desire only by running your own experiments -- remember to generate the random numbers (millions of them) in advance, read them before you start timing, and use the CPU's performance counters (with no other process running, as much as you can stop them from) for accurate measurement!

Answer (score 1):

The speed difference of * / vs + - depends on your processor architecture. In general and with x86 in particular the speed difference has become less with modern processors. * should be close to +, when in doubt: just experiment. If you have a really hard problem with lots of FP operations also consider using your GPU (GeForce, ...) which works as a vector processor.

Answer (score -1):

There is probably very little difference in time between multiplication and addition. division on the other hand is still significantly slower then multiplication because of its recursive nature.
on modern x86 architecture sse instructions should be considered when doing floating point operation rather then using the fpu.Though a good C/C++ compiler should give you the option of using sse instead of the fpu.