# Optimizing divisions in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a situation where I need to divide several different large arrays by the same array:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1000000,))
b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1000000,))
c = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1000000,))
d = np.random.uniform(1, 100, size=(1000000,))

a1 = a / d
b1 = b / d
c1 = c / d
```

I know divisions are slower than multiplications, so I was curious if it would it be faster for me to write:

```py
d_recip = 1 / d
a1 = a * d_recip
b1 = b * d_recip
c1 = c * d_recip
```

Is there is anything numpy already does under the hood to optimize situations like this? If I used cython, would something like this be optimized?

I'm also curious how this applies when the divisor is a scalar:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1000000,))
b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1000000,))
c = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1000000,))
d = 1.65

a1 = a / d
b1 = b / d
c1 = c / d

# faster? or has numpy already optimized this above?
d_recip = 1 / d
a2 = a * d_recip
b2 = b * d_recip
c2 = c * d_recip
```

I understand the reciprocal method won't produce a bit-identical result, I'm just curious how to get the most speed when the exact bits aren't a concern.

Comment: _"divisions are slower than multiplications"_: FWIW, I ran a quick `timeit` on both approaches, and the division approach was consistently _~25% faster_ on my computer. On [tio.run](https://tio.run/##lVHLbsMgELzzFXsLVMQp7q2SPwYMbpHCQ3h9SH/eXRKKKtWHZgVaDTszC2y@4WeKb/vuQ04FAX1wHllDcQv5BnqFmBmzboFFcfHOgEIrmEDDBewdmgpNh3OFc4fF4VYicK0kMSWVRfMbf/xsVaiuaPYvdP7bv@PWoOPDDpo4MQ9FR5vCsEW/pBL4mcq0Vv/lJq5e7yGFYOYp9vwU2x6yK5nqf@kM6/MesxgeiZ/q358kfFyT0dd1apkLWcdkXJnIQDAcD5Tjf5QsFx@RI90Kx7ovqMS@fwM), it's even faster

Comment: In all likelihood, the result is going to depend on your hardware, and possibly on your python implementation.  I'd say don't worry about it unless this really is the bottleneck of your program.  There's value in writing clear code.

Comment: @pho hmm you're right, i'm not actually seeing much/any speed gain, even with the scalar version. I'm pretty sure I'm not wrong about the "divisions are slower than multiplications" bit, there is at least one so post to support me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883240/is-multiplication-faster-than-float-division. I wonder if this is because numpy _is_ doing an optimization, and all i'm doing with the reciprocal is adding another operation? Would love to understand how this is working under the hood.

Comment: @pho [Weird](https://tio.run/##bY/LCgIxDEX3@YosWxlnbN0J8zGVtthFH3QyC/35mnkoyBgSQnLPhaQ86ZHTtbUQS66EFKILBPuU5lieaCZMBcA6j14JeQPkMHhCoXBAK3dJfySKBUdctS/KOwDD61T6apLNsZ9T8LlGcVYdck7h5UahLmt0UoL9Sy8w60ccSLFhu7/fmvBM8w93V0cmJZA@IvoXgVJDIkHsJL3UQEq29gY).

Comment: In my testing `a/d` is 25% slower than `a*d`.  So 3 divides is 3*1.25=3.75 slower.  One divide + 3 multiplies is 3+1.25=4.25.  So predivide should be about 4.25/3.75 slower.  `numpy` doesn't 'optimize' anything across python statements.

Comment: If you care about speed more than the last bits of the calculation, you could also cast to float32, which is typically faster than float64.

Comment: @KellyBundy The effect you see is apparently due to *page faults*. Their impact change a lot from one platform to another (even the OS matters), but they are generally slow and they should be avoided anyway. The reason why the second case is slower is due to the allocations policy of CPython + the libc + the OS : in the first case arrays are better recycled than in the second case (certainly because of some additional CPython allocations, even small ones). It should be better with pre-allocated arrays and in-place operations.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yeah, I also tested on [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY87DsIwEET7PcWUNkoCpkJIOQuyZBtc-KPEKcJVaNLAnai4Ck5waGC1zc6blWZujzimS_DTdB-SqQ_Pl3UxdAnJOm0TlcsPLo6QPXwkUtrACMaPhDwSGzCBLRQvaL-i5CJaLOxrzRqRzLKPTSe9Cq4ZvDWhc6wWFfL29qpbJnbLVJyT-uuezZn_2iljnGA98sdZz6jkmUN_apa2a-s3), where f2 is about 3x slower, and it shows page faults in "Timing details". For f1 it's ~7000 minor page faults, for f2 it's either ~87000 or ~138000 minor page faults. (No major page faults.)

Comment: @JérômeRichard (continuing) But I don't understand the memory allocation. tracemalloc tells me that f1 has peak allocation 8 MB while f2 has peak allocation 16 MB. I'd expect 16 MB for both. Why does f1 not need 8 MB for the division result plus 8 MB for the multiplication result? Surely their lifetimes overlap?

Comment: @JérômeRichard [The tracemalloc test](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZAxbgMhEEWVllNMCdF67XWaKJKrHMOKEDKQIHkGxM4W66ukceMcKqcxS1ilSBAS-v8_DfA_v9LMH5Gu19vEfvP8_fAaMMXMwAFdYNEUTZhmMCNQWi3O5uTQnM_xtASMQljnwQ9SvQgAMPAIcoAtWNWSfUsKm-AANat6QYsnhCk2pT4bshH7iYKPGeVm6KDsMVzcQQ67ujqlhP2XXuCS_8VFicFDIDj6Avn9W7n2aX1RP7LJLFWVvp0pB2Lpe63JoNO6W8B3x7p-3mp0GPMslfodEpNUP122Stdq7w) mentioned above.

Comment: @KellyBundy I haven't done any advanced tests so far, but my guess is that the order of allocation/deletion is slightly different and this order impacts the allocator which is not able to reuse the previously allocated buffers in the second case as good as in the first. Changing the allocator should fix this problem. Any arena/bucket allocator with big pages should be able to handle that properly. I do not know which one of the CPython allocator or the llibc/system one is responsible for this issue. In my experience, this is a fairly common problem with some libc/system allocators.

Comment: @KellyBundy Another possible explanation is that a small allocation done by CPython itself prevent the reuse of a previously allocated buffer (which also causes fragmentation by the way). However, good allocators should use arena/buckets nowadays and not a region-based one. Still region-based ones are used for big chunk of allocated memory because buckets/arena tends to waste too much memory in this case.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I now suspect NumPy optimizes there, noticing in the multiplication of `a * (1 / d)` that it has the only reference to the `1 / d` array, and then overwriting it. I can replicate that with the other version by letting go of the extra reference: [link](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDBTgMhEIbjlaeYI5gtuvViTPoiNg0hBZSkA4SdPWxfpZde9KF8God1V02UkEx-vn9g-C_vZaLXnK7Xt5HC5vHj5jliyZWAIvpIYlFpxDKBHSCV9YiqPXq0p1M-NkAohPMBQi_VkwBeFm5B9nAHTi1ouyLCAjuY2S-953L4bmWhSy6Smy3DVHS1yWXUY4ohV5SbvgPeQzz7nezv59UpJdy_7mZm_tcuGEOAmGAf2BS2B378YZ1TD2Qr8RBNhqWWGhPJoI1JFr0xXTO-eDJzJs6gx1wnqdTPJe0jXxEvSa-JfwI)

Comment: @KellyBundy After a quick check, reducing the size of the allocated array fix the issue so this show this is bad reuse of past buffer certainly due to a region-based memory allocator (though it needs further investigation) : [smaller arrays have no issue](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDBSgUhFIZp61OcpcbcKadNXLhPEiF21RLmqDhnFtOrtLmbeqieJjWHIhJBzv99ivxvH2mjlxgul_eV3OH-8-rJY4qZgDxaT6xPYcW0gV4gpD2irM8W9TzHcwWEjBnrwEkujgwANFwDl3ADRnQydVLcJOEEDe7BVIJ6pbKWGTu3_PcgGdPFC2nMOpiI4xq8ixn5QQ5Q9uJf7YnL27IGIZj5161q4X9lViA48AEeXFHc9Fh-c7d_eFxIZ-Kija6fKftA3I1KBY1WqaGKz5ZU68YotBjzxoX4eSQmLr6r7o3vzX8B).

Comment: @KellyBundy I am not aware of any optimization like that in Numpy so it would be surprising to me. I think this is just a side-effect of allocating more data which causes the allocator to be able to reuse the buffer correctly in your more complex case (or just the fact that the order of the allocation changes). Indeed, `[tmp]` needs to allocate more data.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Interesting, size 32768 has *smaller* peak allocation than 32767: [link](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBPCgIhFIdp6ykerTSmqSmoCDpJREg6JfRUnDeL6Spt2tShOk3qTJsIRJ_6ff753V--o4uzj8ezpXq6eY_GBr0LBGRQG2LDzLboO5ANWP9doiBPGuX16k5pg5AxpWuoKy62DAAkTIBXMAMlGKtdgMbcNBgL--VivVoXkIbNIVLLzEdhF48vg7TKYdlaEyXk06qA2JK846kvhMi4-osnej7_5bNAWDYkA_HeTw_NhQ_GUo8m5qzpmP-mjqjRhY4PF2bfeS76qIbEvsl9AA)

Comment: @JérômeRichard If it *doesn't* do that reference count and overwrite optimization, then I'd expect [these two](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBBbsMgEEXVLaeYJVSOW6ebKlJOUlWIhKFF8gDC44VzlWyyaQ6V0wRTW12kCAlm3gON_vmaJv6O4XL5Gdlt3m9PB08pZgb2hJ7FUoWR0gRmgJDWFmdzRDJ9H48zYBLCogPXSbUTUFbGYewZ9mDgGWQHL2DV4mxXhykVobLHNwXWpsW-3oUpIKQ2m2AjtWPwLmaSm66Bsgd_wr3sXutqlBL2X3uWC3_URcHgwAf4cEVy288ywts6ZjuwySxVLd1ypuwDS9dqHQyh1s0sfiHrmo3VhBTzJJX6-yQmqX6jXhJfk78D) to behave the same, deleting the temp array before the result array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there is anything Numpy already does under the hood to optimize situations like this?

No. **Numpy does not perform special optimizations** on a division like this (see the proof below).

> I know divisions are slower than multiplications

This is indeed generally true. On nearly all platforms. That being said, on recent CPUs, the gap is not huge in practice, especially when Numpy arrays are big.

Actually, *integer* divisions are much more expensive than multiplication (especially 64-bit ones). For example, on Intel Skylake (4-8 years old), a 64-bit integer division can be computed every 21~90 cycle while a 64-bit integer  multiplication can be computed every 1 cycle. For *floating-point* numbers (FP), a *double-precision* (64-bit) division can be computed every 4 cycle, while 2 double-precision (DP) multiplications can be computed every 1 cycle. As we can see, the gap is much smaller for floating-point number though it is still big. Numbers changes from one CPU architecture to another, but all mainstream x86-64 CPUs (Intel & AMD) behave the same way: **divisions are always slower** (both in latency and throughput). Still, integer divisions are much faster on very recent CPUs (while the situation is about the same for floating-point numbers). Indeed, 64-bit integer divisions only takes 7-12 cycles on AMD Zen4, and 10 cycles on Intel IceLake, while 64-bit integer multiplications still take 1 cycle.

In practice, Numpy uses a SIMD-friendly code enabling the C compiler to generate fast *SIMD* instructions (e.g. AVX) so to compute multiple numbers per instruction at runtime. In such a case, the gap between multiplication and division tends to be twice bigger but both can be computed pretty quickly (for a Python code). For example, AVX can compute 4 divisions every 8 cycles (i.e. 0.5/cycle)!

> I was curious if it would it be faster for me to write: [...]

The previous paragraph only matters if the computation is *compute-bound*. The thing is **the computation is memory-bound** on most machines (or close to be). Thus, the time of the divisions is almost irrelevant since **the RAM is much slower than the CPU**. That being said, results can change from one machine to another because **the input/output arrays can fit in the L3 cache of recent high-end CPUs** and the L3 cache is faster than the RAM. Besides, recent high-end machines have 2 DDR5/LPDDR5 RAM channels which can reach a pretty high bandwidth. Numpy may not be able to saturate the RAM on such machines. In this case, the division can be significantly slower on such machines.

Besides, timings can be quite unstable due to the way Numpy *allocate memory*, the OS manage *virtual memory pages*, and the way **CPU caches** operate (not to mention frequency scaling management). Because of that one need to be careful when writing benchmark. On top of that, computing `d_recip` result in more data to be read/written from the RAM and more space required in cache if it would fit (so it is less likely to do so impacting benchmarks). This is partially why some people find the multiplication to be slower.

On my machine with a 40 GiB/s RAM and 4.5 GHz i5-9600KF CPU, 0.5 DP divisions/cycles can be computed. This means the CPU can reach a throughput of `3 * 0.5 * 8 * 4.5e9 / 1024**3 = 50.3 GiB/s` if the RAM would not be the bottleneck <sup>1</sup>. In practice, the throughput of my RAM is slower so multiplications and divisions should be equally fast. **Adding a new temporary step which put more pressure on the RAM being saturated only makes things slower** (some profiling details a provided below).

> If I used cython, would something like this be optimized?

Well, it depends on many parameters... but overall not much.

Using the same code in Cython will have no impact on the performance because Numpy calls are not speed up by Cython. If you use naive basic loops, then the Cython code will behave like Numpy. If you **compute items of `1 / d` on the fly**, then it will reduce the memory pressure so the second code should not be slower than the first on all mainstream machines. Still, **the speed of both codes should be limited by the RAM so one should focus on this point instead of the cost of divisions**. **In-place** computation are the way to go for that. Even better: computing data on the fly so to avoid writing huge arrays in RAM. Arrays should fit in the cache if possible.

---

### Under the hood

Here are some profiling details I got on my machine using numpy-1.26.1 with CPython 3.11.2 on Debian Linux (with GCC).

Here are the timings:

```py
In [10]: %timeit -n 1000 a2 = a * d_recip
736 µs ± 2.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
In [11]: %timeit -n 1000 a1 = a / d
727 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Thus, one can see that the results between a multiplication and a division are the same in this case as expected and explained above.

Performing a Numpy array DP division causes a computing function called `DOUBLE_divide_FMA3__AVX2` to be called, as for DP multiplications it is `DOUBLE_multiply_FMA3__AVX2`. The assembly code of the two respective functions is the following:

```
DOUBLE_divide_FMA3__AVX2:

e3:┌─→vmovupd      0x20(%rcx,%rdi,1),%xmm7               
   │  vinsertf128  $0x1,0x30(%rcx,%rdi,1),%ymm7,%ymm0   
   │  sub          $0x8,%r8                             
   │  vmovupd      0x20(%rdx,%rdi,1),%xmm7              
   │  vinsertf128  $0x1,0x30(%rdx,%rdi,1),%ymm7,%ymm1   
   │  vmovupd      (%rcx,%rdi,1),%xmm4                  
   │  vmovupd      (%rdx,%rdi,1),%xmm5                  
   │  vdivpd       %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0                    <-----
   │  vinsertf128  $0x1,0x10(%rdx,%rdi,1),%ymm5,%ymm2   
   │  vinsertf128  $0x1,0x10(%rcx,%rdi,1),%ymm4,%ymm1   
   │  vdivpd       %ymm2,%ymm1,%ymm1                    <-----
   │  vmovupd      %xmm0,0x20(%rsi,%rdi,1)              
   │  vextractf128 $0x1,%ymm0,0x30(%rsi,%rdi,1)         
   │  vmovupd      %xmm1,(%rsi,%rdi,1)                  
   │  vextractf128 $0x1,%ymm1,0x10(%rsi,%rdi,1)         
   │  add          $0x40,%rdi                           
   │  cmp          $0x7,%r8 

DOUBLE_multiply_FMA3__AVX2:

e3:┌─→vmovupd      0x20(%rdx,%rdi,1),%xmm7              
   │  vmovupd      0x20(%rcx,%rdi,1),%xmm4              
   │  sub          $0x8,%r8                             
   │  vinsertf128  $0x1,0x30(%rdx,%rdi,1),%ymm7,%ymm0   
   │  vinsertf128  $0x1,0x30(%rcx,%rdi,1),%ymm4,%ymm1   
   │  vmovupd      (%rdx,%rdi,1),%xmm7                  
   │  vmovupd      (%rcx,%rdi,1),%xmm3                  
   │  vmulpd       %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0                    <-----
   │  vinsertf128  $0x1,0x10(%rcx,%rdi,1),%ymm3,%ymm2   
   │  vinsertf128  $0x1,0x10(%rdx,%rdi,1),%ymm7,%ymm1   
   │  vmulpd       %ymm2,%ymm1,%ymm1                    <-----
   │  vmovupd      %xmm0,0x20(%rsi,%rdi,1)              
   │  vextractf128 $0x1,%ymm0,0x30(%rsi,%rdi,1)         
   │  vmovupd      %xmm1,(%rsi,%rdi,1)                  
   │  vextractf128 $0x1,%ymm1,0x10(%rsi,%rdi,1)         
   │  add          $0x40,%rdi                           
   │  cmp          $0x7,%r8                             
   └──jg           e3
```

One can see that Numpy use a division as expected and does not perform any special optimizations beside being vectorized using AVX.

More advanced profiling results indicate that nearly all the time is spent in load/store instructions, especially when performing multiplications : the multiplication instructions only stall 5% of the time while the divisions one only stall 32% of the time. My RAM is mostly saturated in both cases (read: 23 GiB/s, write: 9.4 GiB/s). Note that the throughput is limited per core so I expect to reach ~40 GiB/s in parallel with >= 2 cores.

---

### Notes

1 Note that the factor 3 comes from two points :

- the input array must be read and the output array must be written;
- writing data require to write it in Numpy on x86-64 CPUs (due to [cache-line write allocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing))).