# Chrome two times slower to divide in a loop than to multiply in a loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

On Google Chrome, it seems two times slower to divide in a loop than to multiply in a loop.

http://jsperf.com/divide-or-multiply-the-comeback

Any explaination on this behavior ?

Comment: Can we have more tests [here](http://jsperf.com/divide-or-multiply-the-comeback/5), looks like Chrome 39 has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have to do with the js-engine of Chrome, since Vivaldi (1.0.83.38) shows the same result. There is a slight difference in my IE as well.

```
Division:
22,266 
±0.45%
37% slower
```

edit:
This aspect had been discussed to some extent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535605/javascript-performance-divide-or-multiply-vs) already.