# use log value to represent scientific value

Tags: java, floating-point, logarithm, micro-optimization

I recently read some java scientific code which needs to do a lot of multiplications.

The implementation use log value because the developer thought it's faster and preciser.

For example,
If he/she needs to calculate double values `A[1]*A[2]*...*A[n]`, instead, he will let `La[i]=log(A[i])`, and then do `La[1]+La[2]...+La[n]`.

(all value are final so he can reuse. No need to worry about the one time log() operation.)

To me, I am really not sure if this will bring significant performance benefit.

1. I checked online ([What's the relative speed of floating point add vs. floating point multiply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146455/whats-the-relative-speed-of-floating-point-add-vs-floating-point-multiply), and https://agner.org/optimize/). I don't see FP addition being significantly faster than FP multiplication in modern CPUs.
2. I also read IEEE's standard of binary representation of double. I don't think log value can keep more information to make the value preciser, because IEEE standard is doing the same thing.

What do you think?

Comment: Right, FP add is similar performance to FP mul on modern x86.  (Haswell/Broadwell have better mul throughput than add but worse mul latency.  On Skylake their performance is identical).  If you're talking about *integer* logarithms, that's a very different problem.  Integer add is faster, with or without SIMD.  But keeping only the integer part of a log2() is very imprecise, especially for small numbers.

Answer (score -2):

The purpose may not be performance, but handling really big numbers. May be useful when one is dealing with number of atoms in a system, total number of states, etc, which will easily go beyond the floating point range.