# multiply a list by a number until all numbers in list are >=1

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to multiply `y_list` by a number until all numbers in list are `>=1`,
and then just print the new list (without Numpy if it is possible).

Maybe multiply `y_list` as a row and numbers in `i_list=[range(1,20)]` as a column. and then stop when all numbers are bigger than 1.

For example: `y_list= [1.0, 0.5669650111879195]` to  `until y_list=[2.0, 1.12.. ]`

```
y_list= [1.0, 0.5669650111879195]
i=0
while all(y <= 1 for y in y_list):
    i+=1
    if all(y<= 1 for y in y_list):
        break
    print(i)
```

Comment: find lowest number in array and multiply whole array  by 1/(this number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do need to multiply it by a number (let's assume it to be `1.3`) until all the elements are larger than one, the following is the way to go:

```
y_list = [1.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.01]
k = 1.3
while any(y<=1 for y in y_list):
    y_list = [y*k for y in y_list]

>>> print(y_list)
[112.45540695195751, 11.245540695195746, 22.491081390391493, 1.1245540695195746]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is multiply the whole list by the inverse of the smallest term. This will make that term 1 and the rest some factor of it:

```
inverse_min = min(y_list) ** -1
for int in y_list:
    print int * inverse_min
```

The example on [repl.it](https://repl.it/EDoN/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using addition instead of multiplication in this case as processors are much faster in addition than multiplications.

Please see [What's the relative speed of floating point add vs. floating point multiply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146455/whats-the-relative-speed-of-floating-point-add-vs-floating-point-multiply)

Let's assume our sample data is `[-0.4, 1.0, 0.5669650111879195]`

```
y_list= [-0.4, 1.0, 0.5669650111879195]

y_factor = 0
y_min = min(y_list)
if y_min < 1:
    y_factor = 1.0000000000001 - y_min

y_list = [x+y_factor for x in y_list]

print (y_list)
```

Output:

```
[1.0000000000001, 2.4000000000001, 1.9669650111880195]
```

Our resultant array elements are at least greater or equals to 1. See https://repl.it/EDog/0